# Azure IRM with Office Video (O365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office, office-365

As part of my clients current investigation into the feasibility of O365 and the Office Video offering, protection of data is obviously of prime concern. Beyond the encryption at rest technologies now available in Azure, which is awesome, does anyone have experience applying rights management to video content - in the TechNet material there does not seem to be any explicit mention of it being applied to video content but I could b wrong: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj585026.asp

Comment: Seems like this isn't possible right now

Answer (score 0):

So after a little experimentation is doesn't seem possible right now with IRM and Office Video :-(

[image]